# Django creating pdfs

Tags: jquery, python, django, pdf

Im trying to create a simple pdf document using my Django application as per this link

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/
```

The only change is that I'm creating it using a POST request through Jquery...

jquery

```
$("#exportpdf").click(function(){
            //alert('Hi' + '{{request.session.sessionid}}')
            $.ajax({
            async:false
            ,url:'/createpdf'
            ,type: 'POST'
            ,data: {session_id: '{{request.session.sessionid}}'}
            ,error: function(msg){
                alert("Call to Create pdf failed")
            }

        })
        })
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def createpdf(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'
    p = canvas.Canvas(response)
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    return response
```

Problem:

Using the above code when I click exportpdf id(as a post request), the pdf document is not opening(no action is seen/no errors in webserver logs) but when I access the /createpdf link directly as a GET request I can see the pdf document opening properly...

Can't I have a post request and open a pdf document? Should it only be a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your success callback in your ajax call:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

I would add a `.done()` handler

Comment: The server will return the pdf document directly..So, how will I override the done function...ALso, why I dont have problem with get request